# SQL Union Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query in which I join some tables using `union` which is working fine. The problem is I need column from CadastralData_Parcel table which other tables don't have is there any way that I get the column name.

```
SELECT parcel_id ,Parcel_No ,'Planned' as 
     status,Plan_Ar,Plan_NO,City_Ar,Region_Ar
      ,Governorate_Ar
        FROM [DWH_Mapping_V1].[dbo].[CadastralData_Parcel] where 
          Data_Provider_ID=1 and Operation_Type='insert' 
  **union** 
           SELECT parcel_id , Parcel_No, 'Building License'  as 
              status,Plan_Ar,Plan_NO,City_Ar,Region_Ar
              ,Governorate_Ar
              FROM [DWH_Mapping_V1].[dbo].[Licenses_BuildingLicense] where 
              Data_Provider_ID=1 and Operation_Type='insert'
  **union** 
              SELECT parcel_id ,Parcel_No, 'Business License'  as 
                status,Plan_Ar,Plan_NO,City_Ar,Region_Ar
               ,Governorate_Ar
               FROM [DWH_Mapping_V1].[dbo].Licenses_BusinessLicense where 
               Data_Provider_ID=1 and Operation_Type='insert'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, select the column where you can and if you can't, select a constant value or NULL and give it that same column name.

```
SELECT a,column_others_dont_have
FROM ta
UNION
SELECT a,NULL AS column_others_dont_have
FROM tb
UNION
-- ...
SELECT a,NULL AS column_others_dont_have
FROM tn
```